# Show that set subset of polynomials is a subspace, and show dimension of S

Tags: vector-spaces

Let P be the set of polynomials of degree $\leq n$, where $n$ is fixed.

Let S be a subset of P s.t. the polynomials in S satisfy f'(0)= 0 and f(0) = 0. (I'm assuming this means that this set is comprised of all and only the polynomials s.t. plugging 0 into the polynomial and into its derivative both give 0.

I said it was a subspace b/c $f'(0) + g'(0)$ = 0 and $f(0) + g(0) =$ 0. So it is closed under addition. And something similar can be done to show it is closed under scalar multiplication. So it is a subspace.

Correct, so far?

But the part that really trips me up is finding the dimension of S. So I know that the dimension of polynomials $\leq $ n is n+1. What next?

Edit: The current answers seem to be either overly cryptic or more convoluted than needs be.

Let me ask the question this way: is the basis of S = $\{t^2, \dots, t^n\}$ or S = $\{0,0,t^2, \dots, t^n\}$. In the first case, the dim(S) = n-1. In the second case, the dim(S) = n+1.

Comment: Zero **can not be** in a basis!!!!

Comment: silly me. forgot about that. there you solved my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Idea for formal proof of dimension: $f\mapsto f(0)$ and $f\mapsto f'(0)$ are linear functions from the space to ${\Bbb R}$.

EDIT: a basis of the whole space is $\{1,x,x^2,\cdots,x^n\}$.

Comment: I don't see how this helps. I don't see the connection to my question.

Comment: +1: Very nice. @Larry: $S$ is the kernel (null-space) of the transformation described above. What Theorem do you know that relates the dimensions of domain, image and kernel?

Comment: You are making this way more complicated than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $f(t)$ is a polynomial, then $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$ if and only if $t^2$ is a factor of $f(t)$--that is, if and only if $f(t)=t^2\cdot g(t)$ for some polynomial $g(t).$

This is a nice exercise to prove if you don't know this result. More generally, for a polynomial $f(t),$ a scalar $a$, and a positive integer $k,$ we have $$f(a)=f'(a)=\cdots=f^{(k-1)}(a)=0$$ if and only if $(t-a)^k$ is a factor of $f(t).$

---

**Added**: $0$ can *never* be an element of any basis. (Why?) You are correct that $\{t^2,\dots,t^n\}$ is a basis for $S$. Well done!

Comment: What? Why are you speaking in riddles?

Comment: Cameron is giving a easy characterization of the elements of the subspace.

Comment: @larry: My hint should let you explicitly determine a basis for the subspace, by reducing the standard basis for $P$.